# Material-UI : Long Text Wrapped in Grid

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

In the docs of Material-UI, in the section [Grid: white-space: nowrap;](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#white-space-nowrap) there is an exemple of the text wrapped in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4iu23?file=/demo.js).

In this exemple I replace `const message =""` by a long text without space:

`const message ="AsuperLongTextWithNoSpaceItIsVeryAnnoyingIWantToWrapThisSentence"`

The result:

[image]

As you can see the message exceeds the grid.
I want that the message wraps the line.

I tried to add `style={{'overflowWrap': 'break-word'}}` like this:

```
<Paper className={classes.paper}>
  <Grid container wrap="nowrap" spacing={2}>
    <Grid item>
      <Avatar>W</Avatar>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs>
      <Typography style={{'overflowWrap': 'break-word'}}>{message}</Typography> {/* style added */}
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Paper>
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see it's better, but the text exceeds the grid too.

How to do this correctly without going over the grid?

***EDIT (1)***

I have a grid in a grid:

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item>
        <Avatar>
            <ImageIcon />
        </Avatar>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm container >
        <Grid item xs container direction="column" spacing={2} wrap="nowrap">
            <Grid item xs>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle1">
                    {`${props.comment.username}`}
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs zeroMinWidth>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle1" style={{'overflowWrap': 'break-word'}}>
                    {props.comment.comment}
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item container>
                <Grid item>
                        <IconButton onClick={handleMenuClick}>
                            <ThumbUp />
                        </IconButton>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
        <IconButton onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My `container` has `wrap="nowrap"`, my item has `zeroMinWidth`, but the result is:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

***EDIT (2)***

I found the solution:

It must to write `zeroMinWidth` for each `<Grid item>` !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works (note `zeroMinWidth`):

```
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container wrap="nowrap" spacing={2}>
          <Grid item>
            <Avatar>W</Avatar>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs zeroMinWidth>
            <Typography style={{overflowWrap: 'break-word'}}>{message}</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
```

[image: Long text not overflowing container]

Comment: Yes, but I want to display all the text, I want a break line

Comment: Answer updated, just add `overflowWrap` and keep `zeroMinWidth`.

Comment: Thank you, It works, but I want to put this grid in the other grid, I edited my question, could you help me ?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this? It's hard to figure these things out without looking/manipulating the dom.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was more with maxWidth on small screens. Solved with [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: { maxWidth: 250 }.